# Android 14 - Foreground service type for FirebaseMessagingService

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-14

When targeting android 14, we should provide at least one foregroundServiceType for each service in manifest - https://developer.android.com/about/versions/14/behavior-changes-14#fgs-types

Which foregroundServiceType should be used for FirebaseMessagingService?

Should I use this https://developer.android.com/about/versions/14/changes/fgs-types-required#remote-messaging ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`FirebaseMessagingService` by itself is not a foreground service. It operates in  the background and posts a notification whenever it receives one, but it does not do any foreground work.

The [Android 14 changes](https://%20https://developer.android.com/about/versions/14/behavior-changes-14#fgs-types) state that
*"If your app targets Android 14, it must specify at least one foreground service type for each **foreground service** within your app."*
Since it's not a foreground service adding a `foregroundServiceType` should not be required.

I tested this with my own app by sending both foreground and background test messages on Android 14 (target SDK 34) and no `MissingForegroundServiceTypeException` was thrown.

Furthermore the [messaging documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client#manifest) does not include `foregroundServiceType` and I was not able to find any issues related to the topic in the [Firebase Github project](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk).

#### Important Note:

The exception to this would be if you do use your `FirebaseMessagingService` explicitly to do long foreground work and it lives longer than it should (which you probably shouldn't do), then an appropriate `foregroundServiceType` should be required and you should be seeing a `MissingForegroundServiceTypeException` in your logs.

If you're having difficulties with setting up FCM, [this example](https://github.com/DimitarStoyanoff/Notifications) might help.

Comment: is your app in production now without the foregroundServiceType and not having any errors?

Comment: @GauriGadkari Yes, I can confirm that my app is in production without any errors.

Answer (score 3):

Im sick of google changes and duplication. however, any sdks service like admob, google auth, fireebasee. you dont have to  declare anything. you should declarer the type of your own service more info can be found here: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/14/changes/fgs-types-required